# Recommended way to connect cloud foundry to mongodb atlas

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, mongodb-atlas

I've got a spring boot app which is connected to mongodb atlas.
Everything is working locally.

I now want to publish this to pivotal cloud foundry.

## Secure connection between PCF and atlas

In mongodb atlas I need to open up the firewall an allow certain ip numbers.
How should I configure mongodb atlas to connect to pcf in the most secure way?

## Autoconfigure getting in the way

cloud foundry is overriding my connection urls to point to localhost:27017 instead of my atlas cluster.
What is the recommended way to connect to mongodb atlas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In mongodb atlas I need to open up the firewall an allow certain ip numbers. How should I configure mongodb atlas to connect to pcf in the most secure way?

White listing IP addresses for applications that run on CF is not particularly effective.  The reason it's not effective is that you don't know the IP address from which you'll be connecting, because it depends on where Diego decides to run your application.  In other words, it depends on the cell where your application is told to run.  To compound matters, that will change when you restart / restage your application.

Because the IP can vary, what you end up needing to do is white list all of your Cells.  The problem with this and why it's not effective is that you've ended up white listing every app running on the platform.

What you can do to improve the security a bit is to make use of application security groups.  ASG's can be used to limit outgoing traffic.  You can also control them at the space level.  That means you can configure your default running security group to not allow access to your MongoDb server, but you can allow access for individual spaces by binding an ASG to only those spaces with apps that need to talk to your MongoDb servers.

The downside of this approach is that it requires you to be a platform administrator, which means it will only work if you own your CF installation (not going to work for public providers).

More on ASG's here:  https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/app-sec-groups.html

For public providers, you can use a proxy.  To make this work, you need to have your application configured to talk through a proxy when it attempts to access your Mongodb servers.  You control the proxies, which have fixed IPs, so you can white list the proxies to allow access to just your app.  If you don't want to run your own proxy servers, there are public proxy providers that you can use.

> cloud foundry is overriding my connection urls to point to localhost:27017 instead of my atlas cluster. What is the recommended way to connect to mongodb atlas?

It's possible to disable auto configuration.  One way is described in the docs here.  If you include the Spring Cloud Connectors dependencies and use them manually, then the auto configuration will not run.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/spring-service-bindings.html#manual

The other option is to tell the Java build pack not to install the auto configuration.  You can do that by setting the following environment variable for your application, either with `cf set-env` or via a manifest.yml file.

Ex:  `JBP_CONFIG_SPRING_AUTO_RECONFIGURATION='[enabled: false]'`

Be careful if you do this as it will disable everything provided by the auto reconfiguration, which includes setting the "cloud" profile for your app.  If you use this option to disable auto reconfiguration, you'll probably also want to set `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE='cloud'` to manually enable the cloud profile.

I suppose your other option is to simply embrace the auto configuration.  It's a little confusing / magical at first, but I've found this article to explain it very well.

https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/27/binding-to-data-services-with-spring-boot-in-cloud-foundry

Hope that helps!